# Ngx Infinite scroll in angular si throwing error in my project

Tags: angular, npm, nginfinitescroll

I am using Angular version 11.0.4.
I am trying to implement the infinite scroll using `npm` package.
I did every step from the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-virtual-scroller

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: node_modules/ngx-infinite-scroll/src/modules/ngx-infinite-scroll.module.d.ts:1:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of EventCreationModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.
   
This likely means that the library (ngx-infinite-scroll), which declares InfiniteScrollModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
    
    1 export declare class InfiniteScrollModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/ngx-infinite-scroll/src/modules/ngx-infinite-scroll.module.d.ts:1:22 - error NG6003: Appears in the NgModule.exports of EventCreationModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule, Component, Directive, or Pipe class.
   
This likely means that the library (ngx-infinite-scroll) which declares InfiniteScrollModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

If anyone knows how to fix this I will be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is stop the program once and run it again.